# Working with all outlook versions with Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library

Tags: c#, outlook, compatibility

I install Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library, Then
And I programmed using C#.

My app references Outlook 2010 Primary Interop Assemblies.(Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library)

Can I use any Outlook version with this PIA? (Outlook 2000,Outlook 2003,Outlook 2007,Outlook 2010)

In that case, do I need to modify my program to reference the old PIAs?

Comment: If you try to access a property or method relating to a feature not supported on a previous version of Outlook, you will get a `COMException`. If you know your feature history well enough, you can use the most recent version of the PIA to support multiple versions of Outlook.

Comment: any good patterns about it?

Answer (score 2):

"Sort of".

One cannot use any version of Outlook with any PIA call. However, the PIA calls *which are supported by the specific underlying Outlook COM* can be used. The PIA is just a wrapper over the Outlook COM interfaces. (This means that the newer PIA will show methods/properties which *cannot* be used on older clients; see Bradley's comment.)

That is, the new PIAs *will* work with older Outlooks*, insofar as no different PIA must be referenced, because the underlying COM interface has been well defined.

Outlook prior to 2007 misses a good bit of features. Add-in Express offers a (non-free) "Version Neutral API" which favors the lowest-common denominator approach.

*IIRC, at least to Outlook 2000

Happy coding.